# I cannot delete blank folder which I created

Tags: windows-7

*Disclaimer: I don't have english version of W7, I'll try to guess the right captions, but they may not be always accurate. Sorry for that.*

I have a blank folder which I previously created and I want it deleted. However, I get the "Need permissions" error. When I open the Properties window and go to the *Security* tab, it says "You don't have the permission to view or edit security properties for this object".

When I go further and click the  *Details* button on the bottom right, a new window shows, in which I view owners and permissions of this folder. Strangely enough, *Current owner cannot be shown* is written in the *Current owner* box. When I try to assign myself as a full-righted owner of this folder, I get the *Access denied* error.

I'm desperate, can you think of anything? This folder used to contain some photos, but no app used it. Thanks

Comment: You are unable to delete it just now or also after reboot?

Comment: It's been sitting there for a month now. I also tried the 'diagnostic mode' boot (or whatever it's called in english)

Answer (score 1):

You can try some sw like [EMCO MoveOnBoot](http://download.cnet.com/EMCO-MoveOnBoot/3000-2094_4-10397293.html?tag=mncol;1) - here is a little [tutorial](http://www.troublefixers.com/schedule-delete-locked-files-folders-during-restart/). It requires reboot and deletes the file or folder before OS start. According to the tutorial it is compatible with Win 7.

[image]